# При передачи значения методом POST, foreach выбирает первую запись... Помогите пожалуйста

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, веб-программирование

[image]

Есть пользователи с полями, где написаны их ID. Пользователи выводятся методом foreach.

```
<?php foreach ($info3 as $data): ?>
                    <div class="col-lg-4 elastic_person" id="elasticPerson">
                        <div class="card radius-15">
                            <div class="card-body">
                                <div class="media align-items-center">
                                    <div class="avatar_block">
                                        <img src="../<?= $data['avatar'] ?>" class="rounded-circle p-1 border bg-white users_avatar" alt="" />
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="media-body ml-3">
                                        <h5 class="mb-0" id="fioUser"><?= $data['lastname'] ?> <?= $data['firstname'] ?></h5>
                                        <p class="mb-0"><?= $data['patronymic'] ?></p>
                                        <div class="list-inline contacts-social mt-3">
                                            <a href="mailto:<?= $data['email'] ?>" class="list-inline-item"><i class='bx bx-envelope'></i></a>
                                            <a href="tel:<?= $data['telephone'] ?>" class="list-inline-item"><i class='bx bxs-phone'></i></a>
                                            <form action="edit_user.php" method="POST" id="formEdit" style="display: inline">
                                                <input type="text" name="iduser" value="<?= $data['id'] ?>">
                                                <a onclick="document.getElementById('formEdit').submit();" style="cursor: pointer;" class="list-inline-item"><i class='lni lni-play'></i></a>
                                            </form>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Как только отправляется форма в переменную записывается id ПЕРВОГО пользователя, хотя был выбран пользователь с ID = 51.

```
$idUser = $_POST['iduser'];
var_dump($idUser);
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Ребята, подскажите пожалуйста в чем ошибка!

Comment: покажи `var_dump($info3);`

Comment: У Вас же не одна форма, а куча с одинаковым id

Comment: @LaukhinAndrey и это тоже

Comment: сделайте там `id="formEdit-<?= $data['id'] ?>"` и подредактируйте соответственно `onclick="..."`

Comment: если бы вы вообще сделали просто `button type="submit"` вместо этого кривого js, то все бы работало.